# Removing last 5 character from string when creating View in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-view

Im trying to remove the last 5 character of the `name` field in table `dev.roles` which are always `_role` (every role name in that table ends with `_role`). But the SQL query Im writing always goes to the else statement and prints out `NULL` for the entire `users` column. Any feedback is appreciated!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW dev.permissions
AS SELECT
    CASE
            WHEN rls.name::text ~~* '_role'::text THEN ''::text
            ELSE NULL::text
        END AS "users",
    ap.p_create as "insert",
    ap.p_read   as "select",
    ap.p_update as "update",
    ap.p_delete as "delete"
   FROM dev.auth_permissions ap
     LEFT JOIN dev.roles rls ON rls.id = ap.role_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `replace()`:

```
select replace(rls.name, '_role', '')
```

or, if you know they are always there:

```
select left(rls.name, length(rls.name) - 5)
```

Comment: where would this line go... would I just replace the entire case statement?

Comment: @CatGirl19 . . . Yes, I think you can replace the entire `case` expression based on the description of what you want to do.